# reload/refresh UIView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, sdk

I have created an application with multiple views. I have my main view (ViewController.h) and a couple of other views.
The way I call the other views is by presenting modal view and then I go back by dismissing the modal view. Therefore the main view does not close, it stays in the background.

Now, I have a function in one of the "secondary" views that should affect the font size of the primary view. But I cannot find a way to refresh the primary view once I close the secondary view. The font size is saved into a global variable, therefore after I close the secondary view that global variable has a new value and I want this new value to be my font size.

Therefore, I would like to reload the primary view. How can I do that? my button for going back to the primary view has the following code

```
-(IBAction)goBack
{
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Can anybody help me on that?

Thanks a lot guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the viewWillAppear method will always be called when you go from second view to first view... try implementing the changes in this method...

Comment: I have actually managed to reload with setNeedsDisplay, and using NSLog I confirmed that the value passes to the main view, but the font of the text does not change! Is that a problem of "setNeedsDisplay"? does this updates fonts as well?

Comment: Got it to work finally. I used a procedure inside viewWillAppear

Answer (score 1):

might want to try calling `[view setNeedsDisplay]` after the modal view controller is dismissed.

Comment: I have actually managed to reload with setNeedsDisplay, and using NSLog I confirmed that the value passes to the main view, but the font of the text does not change! Is that a problem of "setNeedsDisplay"? does this updates fonts as well?

Comment: What are you trying to change the font to? If you use an invalid font name, for example, you might not see the change you're expecting.